# How to search for a text in a pdf file and highlight it

Tags: android

How to implement text search functionality in a PDF file in android and 
    highlight it.
         I am using the following code to open the PDF file-

```
WebView mWebView=new WebView(MyPdfViewActivity.this);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+LinkTo);
setContentView(mWebView);
```

Comment: Maybe you can downlaod pdf and use "PDFTron Mobile PDF SDK" (https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/mobile/android_pdf_library.html)

Comment: PDFTron Mobile PDF SDK is a paid library, so i don't want to use it if any other library then tell me. @HamedGh

Comment: @sumitsingh have you find any solution?